# Microphone is not working on mac at Dell G3

Tags: macos, microphone

I am currently using Dell G3 and mac os.
My microphone is not working when it comes to mac os.
When I installed Windows or Linux, it works.
Dell G3 doesn't support microphone on mac?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Best guess is Mac OS is not designed to work on Dell... Perhaps better on the Hackintosh stack.

Comment: I don't know which site is the right one for this question - but Stack Overflow definitely isn't it.